# Having trouble with Tumblr API v2 get dashboard requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tumblr

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I keep getting `=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>` when trying to get the posts from dashboard.

```
  consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new( key, secret, {
    :site               => "http://www.tumblr.com",
    :scheme             => :header,
    :http_method        => :post,
    :request_token_path => "/oauth/request_token",
    :access_token_path  => "/oauth/access_token",
    :authorize_path     => "/oauth/authorize"
  })

  request_token = consumer.get_request_token

  # pasting this in url and getting oauth_verifier
  # request_token.authorize_url

  access_token = request_token.get_access_token({:oauth_verifier => 
                                                 params[:oauth_verifier]})
  puts access_token.get('api.tumblr.com/v2/user/dashboard')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `response = access_token.get('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/dashboard')` and then `JSON.parse(response.body)` works.